# How do I set the safe zone size by device?

Tags: ios, swift, view, wkwebview, safearealayoutguide

I want to set a safety zone by device. My web view is set to `SafeArea above`, `SuperView below`. After the `iPhone X` series, the value of `Y` is `44` because of the `notch` area. But for the `iPhone 6` and `iPhone 8`, `44` is too wide. How do I adjust it?

### Area of the current WKWebView

[image]

### Load WebView Area from Current Swift5

```swift
@IBOutlet var WKWebView: FullScreenWKWebView!
...
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        contentController.add(self, name: "goApp")

        config.userContentController = contentController

        WKWebView = FullScreenWKWebView(frame: WKWebView.frame, configuration: config)

        WKWebView.uiDelegate = self
        WKWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        WKWebView.scrollView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(WKWebView)
        view.addSubview(indicator)
...
class FullScreenWKWebView: WKWebView {
    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

I want to set the Top SafeArea area by device.

I am trying things, but is unsuccessful.

### I've set constraints, but the screens on the right and below are cut, and the top is still too wide for the iPhone 6.

[image]

### Top part of iPhone 6

[image]

Comment: why are you setting top above the safe area? give constraint from the safearea!

Comment: @Lion I set it to SafeArea for the iPhone X. 44. The value of my y No more than a safe zone. But the gap is too wide for models like the iPhone 6 because it is a fixed price.

Comment: @Lion I'm sorry but I'm a beginner of Swift and xcode and I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot set the top area of `WKWebView` as a safety zone unconditionally. Because the safety area includes the `NavigationController` Bar Area. But I don't use the `NavigationController`. Therefore, it is not possible to set the safety zone as a constraint.

So I solved the problem by separating by device size.

### Set Main Story Board

[image]

### Adjusting WKWebVIew's Height and Y-Values according to Device Height

```swift
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
if screenHeight > 667 {
            WKWebView = FullScreenWKWebView(frame: CGRect( x: 0, y: 44, width: WKWebView.frame.width, height: WKWebView.frame.height - 44 ), configuration: config)
        } else {
            WKWebView = FullScreenWKWebView(frame: CGRect( x: 0, y: 20, width: WKWebView.frame.width, height: WKWebView.frame.height - 20 ), configuration: config)
        }
```

### iPhone 6

[image]

### iPhone X and after

[image]

Comment: @Lion Here's how I solved the problem: Is this the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

Make the constraint anchored to the safe area and give it the desired value. It will automatically adjust to all devices.

Here you can see a UIView with blue background, anchored top and bottom to the safe area with a 0 value (you can increase the value if you want more distance to the safe area).

[image: Storyboard]
[image: View constraints]

---

The view will be automatically drawn giving the proper distance to the safe area (which is 44 for iPhone X or above, and 0 for iPhone 8 and below).

[image: iPhone X result]
[image: iPhone 8 result]

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a beginner of Swift and xcode and I don't know what to do.

Comment: @iosbegindevel Edited the answer to give more details.

Comment: Did you saw my revised question? I don't think you've seen my revised question.

Comment: Remove the -44 value from the top constraint.

Comment: The top is displayed correctly, but the right screen and the bottom screen are clipped.